# How can I make a 3D shooting game using HTML5 Canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I want to make a 3D shooter (just shooting, no movements or anything) using HTML5 Canvas.

How can I do that? I searched for some tutorials but I couldn't find any good ones.

Comment: I think you're a little ahead of the pack on this one. :) Take a look at this though: http://blog.nihilogic.dk/2008/03/javascriptcanvas-3d-renderer-now-with.html

Comment: @Diodeus I already searched through that website on my search for tutorials...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you know WebGL?
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebGL

Comment: Yeah, but how can i use that to make my game?

Comment: In the section tutorials you have resources to learn, I can't make a game for you :-P http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebGL#Tutorials

Answer (score 4):

First of all I think this question is more suitable for the gamedev stackexchange website (http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/)

As said by the others, you gonna need to learn **WebGL**, which is the **OpenGL ES 2.0** API for the ECMAScript implementation of most browsers. You need a WebGL enabled browser (The latest version of Firefox, Chrome or Safari) and a graphics card driver compatible with OpenGL ES 2.0.

The first thing to learn when beginning with game development imo are the maths about some **matrix and vector operations**. Search the web for some nice and fast tutorials on how to do matrix multiplication, transposition, how to get the determinant of a 4x4 matrix (which is different from getting a 3x3 or 2x2 matrix determinant) and how to invert a matrix should be enough. Then learn some (pretty easy) vector operations, Dot product, Cross product, adition, multiplication, normalization and scaling.

Then learn about the **transformation matrices**, the rotation, translation and scale matrices. And the view and projection matrices as well.

A little of the **GLSL shading language** and what are 3D models (**Vertex positions, normals, texture coordinates and materials**).

Ok, those are the keywords, now google it all. Here is a nice series of tutorials about vector operations for ya: http://www.dickbaldwin.com/KjellTutorial/KjellVectorTutorialIndex.htm

Answer (score 3):

Here is a nice website with 16 starter tutorials

http://learningwebgl.com/blog/?page_id=1217

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for [Canvas with 3D content](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Canvas:3D), has now become [WebGL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebGL).

I found a tutorial: [Learning WebGL](http://learningwebgl.com/blog/?page_id=1217)

Comment: Does the tutorial cover dots as well? Because then you could do a clone of [Penetrator](http://www.rockstargames.com/degenatron/).

Answer (score 1):

You probably want something like [three.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/). It's primarily a WebGL framework, but you can also use/fallback on (2D) canvas.

[Here are some of the 3D canvas demos](http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/).